# PHP: Sum all values of sub array where key is same

Tags: php, mysql, json

**Note: This is not just about summing phone time, phone time needs to calculated seperately through PHP function**

I am currently having following code

```
$i = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

$j = array();

foreach ($i as $item) {
    $month_query_phonetime = $conn->query("SELECT phone_time FROM bigscreen_daily_data WHERE MONTH(work_date) = {$item} AND YEAR(work_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND user_id = 28");

    while ($dataitem = $month_query_phonetime->fetch_object()) {
        $j[][$item] = point_for_phone_time($dataitem->phone_time);
    }
}

print_r($j);
```

this is giving me result as as follows

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => 10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [2] => 48
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [2] => 24
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [3] => 48
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [3] => 48
            )

    )
```

I am trying to get sum of all `[1] => value`, `[2]=> value` and etc as one variable and pass it to indual item in `$j[][$item]` so that it can be used for further processing

i have tried doing

```
while ($dataitem = $month_query_phonetime->fetch_object()) {
    $m = $m + point_for_phone_time($dataitem->phone_time);
}

$j[][$item] = $m;
```

its giving me values as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => {value1}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => {value1+value2}
        )
)
```

and so in order to get desired results which is correct format to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up attaching query to a loop where I want it to be and now its showing intended results

```
foreach ($data as $obj)
{

    $month_query_phonetime = $conn->query("SELECT phone_time FROM bigscreen_daily_data WHERE MONTH(work_date) = {$obj->mon} AND YEAR(work_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND user_id = {$userid} ");

    $m = 0;

    while ($dataitem = $month_query_phonetime->fetch_object()) {
        $m = $m + point_for_phone_time($dataitem->phone_time);
    }

    $obj->prog_point = $obj->prog_point + $m;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly and you're attempting to sum the `phone_time` for each `user_id`, why not let the database do the heavy lifting for you and use an aggregate query:

```
SELECT   user_id, SUM(phone_time) AS sum_phone_time
FROM     bigscreen_daily_data
GROUP BY user_id
```

Chances are it would also execute faster than looping over the `user_id`s, querying all the `phone_time`s for each one, and summing them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Getting MySQL to group by the month and restrict the data set to this year:

```
SELECT   MONTH(work_date) AS m,SUM(phone_time) AS sum_phone_time
FROM     bigscreen_daily_data
WHERE    user_id = 28 AND work_date >= MAKEDATE(year(now()),1);
GROUP BY m
```

Comment: The sum in SQL query is good suggestion but I want to pass individual value of phone time to a PHP function point_of_phone_time() and then store the value of it in individual array so that it can be used for further process, can do 12 queries individually and then merge all of them but that will be lengthy process and un-professional code, that's why trying some way to write in a smaller footprint

Comment: Can you show what point_of_phone_time does? Can it be written as a MySQL function? To optimize it further after than you can look at [summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) which deal for having archived data in a semi preprocessed form.